# Итераторы и перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, мне нужна помощь с перегрузкой оператора ++ (префиксного и постфиксного).

представим что у нас есть контейнер и древо. В древе реализован итератор.
И контейнер его использует, как свой собственный.

```
typedef typename tree::TreeIterator iterator;
```

begin  в данном случае выглядит так:

```
iterator begin()
    {   
        return strom.begin();
    }
```

где strom, это объект типа tree;

базовая часть итератора выглядит так:

```
template < class Tree, class Key, class mapped_type >
struct BaseTreeIterator {

typedef BaseTreeIterator self_type;
typedef std::pair<Key, mapped_type> value_type;
typedef value_type& reference;
typedef value_type* pointer;
value_type* currPair;
Tree* curr;

/** Inequality test operator */
bool operator!=(self_type const & other) const {
    return this->curr != other.curr;
}
/** Dereference operator */

bool operator==(self_type const & other) const {
    return this->curr == other.curr;
}

const self_type& operator++() {
    curr = successor(); // point to next node
    if (curr)
        *currPair = std::make_pair(curr->key, curr->getValue());
    return *this;
}


self_type& operator=(const self_type& other) {
    //проверка на самоприсваивание
    if (this == &other) {
        return *this;
    }
    curr = other.curr;
    currPair = other.currPair;
    return *this;
}}
```

Сама проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно добавить перегрузку ++ оператора.
Дабы он поддерживал данные функции

```
using mp = lib::PersistentMap<int, int>;
using mp_it2 = mp::iterator;
mp_it2 tmp1;
mp_it2 tmp2 = ++tmp1; // ругается на ++
mp_it2 tmp3 = tmp1++; // ругается на tmp1
mp_it2 tmp4(tmp1++);
```

Но я не представляю, к чему привязать данную перегрузку.
И как сделать сохранение значений постфикса.

Буду благодарен совету и/или примеру.

Comment: Для описания постфиксного оператора добавьте int в скобки: const self_type& operator++(int);

Answer (score 1):

Нашел на форуме.

```
 // prefix increment (++it)
  iterator& operator++() {
      ++p;
      return *this;
  }

  // postfix increment (it++)
  iterator operator++(int)
  { return iterator(p++); }
```